# Why does accessing certain properties from the result from Invoke-WebRequest open my browser?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

When accessing URLs within our company's intranet, which are secured via [WIF passive authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx), powershell decides to open my default web browser, and it navigates to the URL specified in my `iwr` command, when I access certain properties on the result.

This does not occur, when I point the target to something like google.com.

Can anyone explain this (crazy)behavior, and how I could prevent it?

**Code Example**

```
$response = (Invoke-WebRequest 'http://myhost.example.com/MyApp/' -UseDefaultCredentials)
write-host $response.GetType()
write-host $response.StatusCode
$response.Forms[0] # causes browser to open, but does return the content!
# comment out the above line, and no browser opens
```

**Output**

```
>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject
>200
>
>Id              Method  ...
>hiddenform      post    ...
```

**Fiddler HTTP Summary**

```
GET  302  http   myhost.example.com   /MyApp/           powershell_ise
GET  401  https  sts.example.com      /default.aspx?... powershell_ise
GET  401  https  sts.example.com      /default.aspx?... powershell_ise
GET  200  https  sts.example.com      /default.aspx?... powershell_ise
GET  302  http   myhost.example.com   /MyApp/           chrome
GET  401  https  sts.example.com      /default.aspx?... chrome
GET  401  https  sts.example.com      /default.aspx?... chrome
GET  200  https  sts.example.com      /default.aspx?... chrome
POST 200  http   myhost.example.com   /MyApp/           chrome
GET  200  http   myhost.example.com   /MyApp/           chrome
```

Comment: If your trying to fill out the form you need to use `$response.Forms[0].property`. Also, have you tried running `Invoke-RestMethod http://myhost.example.com/MyApp/ -body $response.Forms[0]` (after filling out form)

Comment: I'm not trying to fill out a form, I'm trying to make a request, and obtain the contents of the request form property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an issue with similar behaviour. What I've found so far may help you narrow down your issue.

*tl;dr - add option -UseBasicParsing to the request*

I have a SAML-protected web service that uses http 302 redirects to serve a login form. My script follows the redirects, submits the forms (there are three), and eventually gets to make a rest request against the original service URI.

There is only one step that causes a browser to open - when the authentication service responds with a pre-filled form in an html page with some onload(submit()) script up top. The correct behaviour is to submit the form immediately.

The fragment of code that causes a browser to open is

```
$results.Forms["Response"].Fields["LARES"]
```

I can access any other part of the response, including the Content (which includes the form in raw html) but any attempt to evaluate the LARES value or the form that contains it causes a browser to open against the fully qualified URI from the ACTION attribute of the form.

The way to fix this, and still get at the data, is to turn off the DOM parsing that's forcing Windows to use the IE browser to get involved. Adding the option -UseBasicParsing to the Invoke-WebRequest prevents the browser from getting involved. This means the Forms[] array won't be filled in, but the InputFields[] array is still available.

So, instead of accessing

```
$result.Forms["Response"].Fields["LARES"]
```

I now access

```
$result.InputFields[0].VALUE
```

where $result.InputFields[0].NAME is "LARES".

Comment: Adding `-UseBasicParsing` to `Invoke-WebRequest` stopped powershell from triggering my default browser to open links when accessing the response object. Thank you!